# How to stop the "Changed database context to ..." message

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Is there some way to stop the `Changed database context to ...` message when the piece of SQL has a `USE database` in it ?

Comment: Where do you get these messages? I've never seen one before.

Comment: @ta.speot.is you see them, for example, when using `SQLCMD.exe`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to set the [errorlevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) of `sqlcmd`, which defaults to 0. Note: don't confuse the errorlevel here with the exit code of `sqlcmd` that is returned to, say, `cmd.exe` as the `ERRORLEVEL`.

To disable this message for all of an `sqlcmd` session, use the `-m` commandline option:

```
sqlcmd -m 1 <other options>
```

To disable this message for a block of code, use the `:setvar` batch command:

```
USE [mydb]
GO

-- Disable message for next USE command
:setvar SQLCMDERRORLEVEL 1
USE [mydb]
GO

-- Reenable
:setvar SQLCMDERRORLEVEL 0

...
```

To use the `:setvar` (or other SQLCMD batch commands) in Management Studio, you need to enable the SQLCMD mode for the query window you're in (menu "Query / SQLCMD Mode"). You'll see that it is enabled, when lines starting with ':' have a gray background.

Comment: Hi, I got this message when running an application built using delphi. I need to modify the databases in between.Your way is working in SQL management studio but when i tried to pass the cmd from code i got error as "Incorrect syntax near '@P1'.Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: @kvsbhavani That is expected. The `:setvar` syntax is part of the so called "batch mode", which is only supported by SQLCMD.EXE and SSMS (see the last paragraph of my answer). If you are handling this in your own code I suggest you post a new question on SO.

Comment: I saw in 14 version of SqlCmd that `SQLCMDERRORLEVEL` = 1 hides only "Changed database context to ..." and doesn't hide the PRINT output. But you can get troubles if anybody users older versions of SqlCmd.

Comment: In this case `GO` seems to be required. I usually end my use statements with just a semi-colon, but including `GO` was the only I could get this to work.  Actually, adding the `:setvar` statements without the `GO` just made it so not even adding `-m 1` to sqlcmd call would suppress the "context changed" messages.

Answer (score 7):

I release updates by having SQLCMD run all my .sql scripts in a directory. But when you start everything with a USE myDB you get a repetitive changed context message in the log file, which is dull. So I use this one liner instead.  If the context is actually changed, you still get the message, which is good.

IF EXISTS(SELECT [DB_NAME()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189753.aspx) WHERE DB_NAME() not IN ('myDB')) USE MyDB

Comment: This is a great idea as it means I can run the script in the query window (without having to turn SQLCMD mode on) and use it in  with SQLCMD without it obscuring error messages because of the repeated context change output.

Answer (score 6):

Another idea is to use three-parts names in your SQL, e.g. instead of...

`USE Pubs; SELECT name FROM dbo.Authors;`

...write...

`SELECT name FROM Pubs.dbo.Authors;`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer ... not sure I fancy disambiguating all my code   :-)

Comment: possibly it didn't work for me because I still had the mssql_select_db call after connecting (which afaik also issues a USE command)... I don't know - I solved the problem by adding a SELECT 1 after every USE (like user2335044 suggested)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, an easy and simple solution was to run a small query first, such as `SELECT 1;`. The message `Changed database context...` was therefore coupled to this first query and the following queries were retrieved without this error message.

Comment: I got this message while executing a PHP query that previously was working. To fix the issue I've incremented the mssql.timeout value in php.ini from 60 to 120.

The problem arose because a query was taking more than 60 seconds and the DB/Driver? (freetds) was giving "Changed database context to" message instead of a more meaningful and related error to a timeout problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: add `-m 1` to your `sqlcmd` command line arguments.

Comment: This has [already been mentioned in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10412792/4957508). Once you have sufficient reputation, you will be able to vote up Answers that you found useful.