# Changed database context to 'sqldbname' error with classic asp

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

Theres been a few questions with this but as far as I know/believe they don't help me at all. My code was working fine previously. But for some reason stopped. My sql server version is 2012. The specific error is:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] Changed database context to 'sqldbname'
```

My ASP code:

```
<!--#include file="connv.inc"-->
<%
n=Request.form("total")
response.write(n)

for x = 0 to n-1
ttitle=Request.form("title_"&x)
title=Replace(ttitle, "'", "''")
id=Request.form("id_"&x)
views=Request.form("vViews_"&x)
likes=Request.form("vLikes_"&x)
description=Request.form("vDescription_"&x)

sql="INSERT INTO tbl_videos(videoTitle, videoId, videoLikes, videoViews, videoDescription, swamCompatible) values ('"&title&"', '"&id&"', '"&likes&"', '"&views&"', '"&description&"', '0')"
connv.execute(sql)
response.write(sql&"<br>")
next
%>

<html>
<head>
<title> Updating Tables </title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

<!--#include file="closeEmv.inc"-->
```

connv.inc code:

```
<%
set connv = server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
connv.open "DRIVER={SQL SERVER}; SERVER=52.2.8.73; UID=myuid; PWD=mypwd; DATABASE=sqldbname"
%>
```

Comment: Lets start with the basics... is `sqldbname` a valid database name on your server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop the "Changed database context to ..." message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412673/how-to-stop-the-changed-database-context-to-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your connv.inc code with below part,

```
<%
set connv = server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
connv.open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=52.2.8.73; Initial Catalog=sqldbname; User ID=myuid; Password=mypwd"
%>
```

Comment: that worked. thanks! do you know what the issue was? I didn't touch my connection string when doing edits today, and previously it worked.

Comment: I think some OS or driver updates should have caused this issue. This is just a different way of connecting the DB.

Comment: @JonathanLin You haven't fixed anything you have just switched one connection type for another. You were using [SQL Server ODBC Driver](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-sql-server-odbc-driver/) this answer changes that to the [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/).

Comment: @JonathanLin It all depends on what version of SQL Server you are using if you are using SQL Server 2005 you should be using the [SQL Native Client 9.0 OLE DB Provider](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-9-0-oledb-provider/) or higher but after SQL Server 2000 you should be using a [SQL Native Client OLE Provider](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-9-0-oledb-provider/) to support types like `nvarchar(max)` for example *(worth noting SQL Native Client 9.0 is backward compatible)*.

Comment: well the error appeared seemingly randomly. but disappeared after changing this so from my perspective it fixed my problem.

Comment: @JonathanLin Yes but it changed not because you found the issue causing the database context changed warning but because the connection type was completely changed. Think of it this way if I had a old car that started playing up I can try to fix it or I can buy another car, this solution is like buying a different second hand car.

Comment: @JonathanLin This may help you find what caused the "change of context" in the first place - http://stackoverflow.com/q/10412673/692942

Comment: @JonathanLin Don't get me wrong changing the Provider/Driver type in the connection string obviously helped but I would rather you had been given the right advice as to what to change it to *(to be fair at the time, no body knew what SQL Server you were using so this wouldn't have been straightforward)*. As it stands your using SQL Server 2012 so wouldn't recommend using the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server as this answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Following one from [my comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458847/changed-database-context-to-sqldbname-error-with-classic-asp#comment50908785_31459665)

> [@JonathanLin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4978506/jonathan-lin) You haven't fixed anything you have just switched one connection type for another. You were using [SQL Server ODBC Driver](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-sql-server-odbc-driver/) this answer changes that to the [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/).
>
> [@JonathanLin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4978506/jonathan-lin) It all depends on what version of SQL Server you are using if you are using SQL Server 2005 you should be using the [SQL Native Client 9.0 OLE DB Provider](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-9-0-oledb-provider/) or higher but after SQL Server 2000 you should be using a SQL Native Client OLE Provider to support types like nvarchar(max) for example *(worth noting SQL Native Client 9.0 is backward compatible)*.

You should trying to use the most up to date provider which for the balance of features and backward compatibility *(you haven't stated what version of SQL Server you are using)* I would recommend using [SQL Native Client 9.0 OLE DB Provider](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-9-0-oledb-provider/).

If this is not installed on your web server you will need to [download](https://www.connectionstrings.com/download-sql-server-native-client/) and install it first.

```vb
<%
Set connv = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connv.open "Provider=SQLNCLI; Server=myServerAddress; Database=myDataBase; Uid=myUsername; Pwd=myPassword;"
%>
```

Using this provider will ensure you have access to features as you upgrade from earlier versions of SQL Server without requiring you to mess with your connection string. Features such as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` *(which was first supported with SQL Server 2005)*.

---

### Side Note:

Also instead of opening your connection inside an `#include` file consider storing the connection string as a string variable and only instantiating the `ADODB.Connection` when it is needed.
In fact when using `ADODB.Command` to execute SQL Server commands the connection string variable can be passed to `ActiveConnection` property of the command object and the command object will instantiate the `ADODB.Connection` for you. This way when the command is closed so is the connection.

Comment: my sql server is 2012. Also currently I'm not 100% certain where everything will be stored, as such I prefer to keep installations at a minimum.

Comment: @JonathanLin In which case you should be using [SQL Server Native Client 11.0 OLE DB Provider](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/) to make sure that all specific SQL Server 2012 features are available to ADO. Just replacing `Provider=SQLNCLI` with `Provider=SQLNCLI11` should be enough as long as the SQL Native Client 11.0 is installed on the web server *(use link in answer above if not)*.

Comment: well no difference it seems okay

Comment: @JonathanLin Shortsighted view but each to their own just don't try using any of the `MAX` datatypes in SQL Server then wonder why your code isn't working. Just out of interest do you even understand the differences I've explained?, if you did you wouldn't expect an instant difference. Good luck anyway.

Comment: well when I said no difference I meant I switched it to your connection string and there seemed to be no difference. Also, i havent used any max datatypes, just changed them to about 50. and what differences you explained? between the providers?

Comment: @JonathanLin Yeah because it's not like you'll have to deal with connection strings and data providers is it??

Comment: I'm already doing them and mine work fine. So idk whats the matter.